# Objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape (Barchart)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot bar chart using matplotlib but its showing me this error message
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Here is my code:

```py
print(lol)
    
X = numpy.arange(3)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(X + 0.00, lol[0], color = 'b', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.25, lol[1], color = 'g', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.50, lol[2], color = 'r', width = 0.25)
plt.show()
```

Here is my output with error message:
Here the data is the one which need to be plotted in the bar chart
its stored in `lol` in the form of `list` of `list`.

```py
[[0, 21, 0, 15, 0, 4, 11, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 32, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 11, 0, 3, 10, 0, 1, 0, 0, 11, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1], [135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 135, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0], [143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 143, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0]]
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\Pyton Excel Extractions\dashboard.py", line 68, in <module>
        ax.bar(X + 0.00, lol[0], color = 'b', width = 0.25)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1438, in inner
        return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2430, in bar
        x, height, width, y, linewidth = np.broadcast_arrays(
      File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in broadcast_arrays
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 258, in broadcast_arrays
        shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
      File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\stride_tricks.py", line 189, in _broadcast_shape
        b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
    ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Help me out!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing `arange(3)`? the length of `X` and `lol[0]` are not the same.

Comment: I will give it a try after sometime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64279766/graph-is-not-displaying-when-i-enter-the-value-in-dash-framework  This one @Grayrigel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` and `lol[0]`, `lol[1]` and `lol[2]` have different lengths (`3` and `99` respectively). Changing the length of the `X` gives the following output. Does this help?

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lol=[[0, 21, 0, 15, 0, 4, 11, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 32, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 11, 0, 3, 10, 0, 1, 0, 0, 11, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1], [135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 135, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0], [143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 143, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0]]

#changing the length of X such that it matches lol[0],lol[1] etc.
X = numpy.arange(len(lol[0]))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.bar(X + 0.00, lol[0], color = 'b', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.25, lol[1], color = 'g', width = 0.25)
ax.bar(X + 0.50, lol[2], color = 'r', width = 0.25)

plt.show()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Based on your comment something like this would be nice. Here I am making use `pandas`:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lol=[[0, 21, 0, 15, 0, 4, 11, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 32, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 11, 0, 3, 10, 0, 1, 0, 0, 11, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 1, 9, 1, 6, 3, 7, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 3, 0, 1], [135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 135, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 0, 0, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0, 135, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 135, 0], [143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 143, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 0, 0, 143, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0, 143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 143, 0]]


df = pd.DataFrame(lol).T
df.columns = ['1st Month','2nd Month', '3rd Month']
df['Product'] = numpy.arange(len(lol[0]))

#if you don't like subplots keep subplots=False
df.plot.bar(x='Product',subplots=True, figsize=(20,10)) 
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[image]

Comment: Yeah I saw it worked Thanks can you help me out in this the values entered in lol are in list of list format so basically it is first list is the count of product of first month and then second list count of product of second month and so on there are 99 products so I need to have 99 different colors for each product count plot and  all 99 products must be arranged like in lol means monthly based so how to do it

Comment: Yeah sure I will

Comment: I have added an answer. 99 columns will be too much I think. I think it will look nice if you introduce subplots.

Comment: Ok man I understood your approach but one last thing it's that I need each product to be having different color so that it can be identified in one month which product has the highest sale or lowest and all.....

Comment: I also want to display the name of products having specific color the names are defined in a list  @Gabyrigel