# Graph is not displaying when I enter the value in textbox using dash framework

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, plotly-dash

I have the data in a list and when I return the dcc.Graph then it doesn't return anything just a blank graph is displayed in front of me

Let me explain the code to you all
In this code I want user to enter product name and if the product name is present in the table and the bottle column is greater  than 0 then select those rows data.
Now we have some rows having month and bottle(quantity)
the month is repetitive as one product is there many times in one month with different bottle(quantity) so now I am calculating the unique months quantity of bottle sold
After that I am inserting the unique month list and calculated quantity list to the data list as shown
This data list is appearing correctly in the output as per my needs
But after that I want it to be plotted in bar chart but its not working for me.
So help me out here.

Code Snippets:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="",
  db="trial"
)

cursor = db_connection.cursor()

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
   html.H4('Sales Of February 2020 by MHD'),
   html.Label('Product Name: '),
   dcc.Input(
       id='tfield',
       placeholder='Enter the product name',
       type='text'
       ),
   html.Br(),html.Br(),
   html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='my-output')])
])

@app.callback(Output('my-output','figure'),[Input('tfield', 'value')])
def callback(input_value):
    df = pd.read_sql("select Month,Bottle from merge where Bottle>0 and ProductName=%s", db_connection,params=(input_value,))
    mon=[]
    data=[]
    quan=[]
    uni_mon=[]
    uni_quan=[]
    y=0
    su=0
    
    for i in df.itertuples():
        mon.append(i.Month)
        quan.append(i.Bottle)
        
    uni_mon=list(set(mon))
    v=len(quan)
    
    for x in uni_mon:
        su=quan[y]
        while((y<v-1) and (mon[y]==mon[y+1])):
            su=su+quan[y+1]
            y=y+1
                
        y=y+1
        uni_quan.append(su)

    data.append({'x':uni_mon,'y':uni_quan,'type':'bar','name':input_value})
    print(data)
    figure={
        'data':data,
        'layout':{
            'title':'Graphhhh',
            'xaxis':'Month',
            'yaxis':'Quantity'
            }   
        }

    return figure

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server(debug=False)
```

so result on shell is

```
    Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app "dashnew" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2020 18:36:33] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2020 18:36:33] "[37mGET /_dash-layout HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2020 18:36:33] "[37mGET /_dash-dependencies HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
[{'x': [], 'y': [], 'type': 'bar', 'name': None}]
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2020 18:36:33] "[37mPOST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
[{'x': ['2月サマリー', '2月サマリー (Feb Sales)'], 'y': [1260, 4275], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'M&C Brut Blan'}]
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2020 18:36:36] "[37mPOST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
```

this is my result when I enter and no graph is  shown on server

[image: Server result]

please help me out here I have updated my entire code and output that I am receiving while executing this code.
I want to get the bar chart in the browser where its showing blank graph
Its displaying blank graph to me whether I enter a product name or not.
Help me out!

Comment: It would make it easier to debug your code, if you wrapped up a MWE, i.e. a piece of code that runs (and demonstrates you issue).

Comment: Hi Prateek, I received your email. It's hard to say the problem. What is the error message that you're getting? CharmingData

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for replying the error is the last screen that's there in above question where it's returning blank graph while I have entered the product name in the text field but on second last code snippet you can see at the end the data is retrieved correctly so why isn't it plotting that on graph @Adam Schroeder

Comment: Hi @prateek_pro
It's not plotting because you're appending the dataframe incorrectly. When you print(data) you get an empty x and y. An empty list shows:
[{'x': [], 'y': [], 'type': 'bar', 'name': None}]

I'm not sure what, but you have to filter or append the dataframe differently, otherwise, there is no data to plot

Comment: Yeah but have a look after that it's showing values in it so that's what need to be plotted but not working. I think at first it's showing blank as the text field is firstly blank when user clicks on it @AdamSchroeder

Comment: emmm... That's weird, I'm not sure why it's not plotting. Sorry @prateek_pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this :

```
figure={
    'data':data,
    'layout':{
        'title':'Graphhhh',
        'xaxis':{'title':'Month'},
        'yaxis':{'title':'Quantity'}
        }   
    }
```